# Plotting hourly data with Series.plot()

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, series

I have a csv file that looks like such:

```
df = pd.read_csv('book1.csv',  header=1)

    Index   Date Time      DEMAND
    0   2005-03-01 06:30:00 1
    1   2005-03-01 06:45:00 2
    2   2005-03-01 07:00:00 4
    3   2005-03-01 07:15:00 0
    4   2005-03-01 07:30:00 10
    5   2005-03-01 07:45:00 13
```

I would like to plot this, but when I call   df.plot(), I get the error:

```
df.plot()

ValueError: view limit minimum -36601.34583333333 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

I have also tried creating my time series this way:

```
pd.Series(data=df['DEMAND'], index=df['Date Time'])
```

But the result is that the data turns null:

```
Date Time
2005-03-01 06:30:00   NaN
2005-03-01 06:45:00   NaN
2005-03-01 07:00:00   NaN
2005-03-01 07:15:00   NaN
2005-03-01 07:30:00   NaN
2005-03-01 07:45:00   NaN
2005-03-01 08:00:00   NaN
2005-03-01 08:15:00   NaN
2005-03-01 08:30:00   NaN
```

I'm looking for

1)advice on why these methods are failing, and/or

2)alternative way to get my desired result.

Thanks!

Comment: You have two columns and an index in your df. Which part to you want to have on the x and which on the y axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did come up with one solution:

```
x = df['Date Time']
y = df['DEMAND']

plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

still interested in figuring out why I'm having issues with my methods.